# How to show in progressbar 100% before closing

Tags: c#, wpf, progress-bar, user-experience

I am using a progress bar to show the progress to the user in a time consuming operation.My problem is,while i am doing the operation the backgroundworker can't report any progress until it is completed.So if i have only one iteration,the progressbar always shows 0% and when it is finished,the progressbar gets closed immediately.So the user does not gets the impression that the task is completed.I am looking for a way to let the user know that the task is completed before the progessbar gets closed.My code is as below.

```
            this.progressDialog = new progressDialog();

            Dispatcher pdDispatcher = ((Window)this.progressDialog).Dispatcher;

            this.worker = new BackgroundWorker();
            this.worker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
            this.worker.ProgressChanged += new  ProgressChangedEventHandler(worker_ProgressChanged);
            this.worker.DoWork += delegate(object s, DoWorkEventArgs args)
            {
                foreach (Element id in state.Elements)
                {
                    if (this.worker.CancellationPending)
                    {
                        args.Cancel = true;
                        return;
                    }

                    UpdateProgressDelegate update = new UpdateProgressDelegate(this.UpdateProgressText);
                    pdDispatcher.BeginInvoke(update, Convert.ToInt32(((decimal)state.Elements.IndexOf(id) / (decimal)state.Elements.Count()) * 100), state.Elements.Count());

                    Element newElement = this.Item.Copy(id);
                    if (newElement .HasValue)
                    {
                        state.CreatedElements.Add(newElement.Value);
                    }
                }
            };
            this.worker.RunWorkerCompleted += delegate(object s, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs args)
            {
                if (!(args.Error == null))
                {
                    throw args.Error;
                } 
                this.UpdateDisplayItems();
                this.progressDialog.Close();
                this.progressDialog.Dispose();

            };

            this.worker.RunWorkerAsync();
            this.progressDialog.Show();            
        }

        void worker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.progressDialog.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
        }
    public void UpdateProgressText(int percentage, int recordCount)
    {
        this.progressDialog.Description = string.Format("{0}% of {1} Records", percentage.ToString(), recordCount);
        this.progressDialog.Value = percentage;
    }
```

Comment: I don't see you calling `worker.ReportProgress` anywhere in your `DoWork` function?

Comment: @Dennis I am using UpdateProgressText delegate to invoke the percentage to my progressdialog

Comment: progressDialog is custom dialog? Do you binding progressDialog.Value to ProgressBar Control? It would be nice if you can share progressDialog's code.

Comment: why is it u're using the UpdateProgressText instead of the built in ReportProgress method?

Answer (score 2):

In this type of situation, you might want to consider setting the `IsIndeterminate` property to true and forget about setting the value.  This will give you a marquee effect, so the user get's the impression that something is happening.

Comment: @biju Yeah, if you're not getting any feedback from the worker thread then just marquee it and be done.

Answer (score 0):

Two options I can think of:

1. When the work is done, don't close it immediately. Instead, set a timer to close it and set the progress to 100% for enough time for the user to see it.
2. Round the percentage up by, say, 5 points, so the progress bar actually *shows* 100% complete for the time between 95 and 100%.